# Assembly - using more than 2 buttons for interrupts?

Tags: assembly, microcontroller, interrupt, atmega

I am using STK200 board with Atmega8535 microcontroller. I use INT0 and INT1 buttons as external interrupts, but in order to initialize INT0 I have to set bit 6 to 1 and to intialize INT1 I have to set bit 7 to 1, so there is no more space to initialize other buttons.

I have been told by my lecturer that it is possible to use more buttons to cause interrupts but that it is above the knowledge required for the year that I am studying (1st year Software Engineering).

Without interrupts, I have no idea how to handle buttons. So I need either suggestions how to handle buttons or how to use more buttons as interrupts.

Comment: Your lecturer might have been referring to the Pin Change Interrupt (`PCINT`) which allows you to have interrupts triggered by changes on any of the PBn, PCn and PDn pins. Google for it and I'm sure you can find some material to read.

Comment: Did you try it?.How was it?

Answer (score 0):

There is another way for handling buttons(different from interrupts), of course interrupts are the best, but if you don't have any external interrupt pins left, then you could use this. The method is basically about polling the pin where you have connected the button. I'll post you the code implementation in asm for 8051, so you can understand it better. Hope it helps:

;assume you have connected the button to P1.1

```
org 00H
 jb P1.1,$      ;wait for a hold button    
 jnb P1.1,$     ;wait for button to be unhold
 ;perform anything
 end
```

As you can see in the second line of code I check if the button was pressed(assuming button active low of course), if wasn't then I stay there, if it is pressed then I jump to line 3 where I wait until the button is unholded. If you don't wait until the btn is unholded then  the microprocessor will perform ehat you want to do lots of times for only one press btn.The cause of this is simple:the frequency of the mP(could be 12MHz) is much faster than the frequency of your finger pressing button,or,in other words: You can press the button as fast as you can but the mP will always be faster than you:).
Note: Interrupts are better than this for a simple reason: they don't have to do the polling.

Hope you understand.

Comment: One issue with this code is that it requires a hardware debouncing, since the code does not do any debouncing itself